# Mass criteria query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access query. I need a mass 'like' criteria.

Normally it's "Like "Apple" or "Orange"". However, I have over 400 words.

How do make this happen without manually typing in a Like formula by hand with the 400 words?

Is there a way to do this by referencing a table or form?

Answer (score 0):

As for "referencing a table", you can actually do a join using `LIKE` instead of `=`.

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  target t
INNER JOIN
  SearchList s
ON t.name LIKE '%' + s.term '%'
```

In this case, SearchList is a table you create just for this task with just 1 column containing the terms you want to search for.

Comment: @lucky123, you'll need to substitute the Access '*' wildcard for the SQL '%' wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in clause , sub query to get result, the query in Access [can have 64000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699554/maximum-length-of-a-sql-query-in-microsoft-access-2010) characters so your 400 words X 5 chars in each approximate , 2000 chars + 50 chars SQL statement, should be OK,

Select * from tblVitalInfo where ObjectName in ('Apple','Banana','Pitch')

But I will recommend following better way of doing same,

1. Assume the table tblVitalInfo(ID, ObjectName) , and searching ObjectName

I would create a table tblWordList(ID autonumber primary key, SearchString Text(200)) . Write Insert statement to add all the words to search e.g. Insert into tblWordList(SearchString) values('Apple') ; execute these queries in Access. OR you can open the table to add data  , easier than insert statement.

2. Run the following query
   Select  * from tblVitalInfo where ObjectName in (Select SearchString tblWordList)